# How to make Underline of TextInputLayout's edittext Round Corner

Tags: android, android-layout, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I want to make round corner's of bottom line in TextInputLayout Filled Text from Material Design. I am able to change the color of it in focused and unfocussed mode but how to change the corner of it to be round shape.
This is what I have now-

[image]

And I am looking for following results-

[image]

This is the code I try but didn't do much -

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/Rounded_ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/selector_otp_input_box_stroke_color"
        app:boxStrokeWidth="6dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="5dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="5dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="5dp"
        app:boxCollapsedPaddingTop="5dp"
        app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="6dp">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:digits="1234567890"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

**Style Rounded_ShapeAppearanceOverlay**

```
<style name="Rounded_ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"
        parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">

    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">4dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">4dp</item>
</style>
```

Any work would be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Are u saying that each box is a `TextInputLayout` in the above design ? So u have 6 TextInputLayout for this design ?

Comment: @ADM yes you are right, I was trying to create OTP field with changing color of bottom line with each focus, so I came with this implementation, everything is perfect except the rounded corners of bottom line

Comment: This can be very tricky to implement with 6 `EditText` because u have to handle the focus change each time plus u also have handle text deletion, in a nutshell it can lead to bugs . This should implemented with a Single Edit text So u better customize `EditText` to work in this way.  to get Started just search for `PinEntryEditText`  u will get the idea.

Comment: @ADM I earlier tried with different approaches like you said with one editText, now settle with above one along with a TextWatcher on editText, I can try again with more intanse approach with only one EditText but it will be great if there is any option I can make underline of TextInputLayout with rounded corner...

Answer (score 0):

For Curve Follow below code
For Layout

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:digits="1234567890"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:maxLength="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/focus_tint"
        android:background="@drawable/underline"/>
```

Add this in your TextInputEditText

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/focus_tint"
android:background="@drawable/underline"
```

underline.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:gravity="bottom">
        <shape>
            <size android:height="4dp" />
            <solid android:color="#000000" />
            <corners android:radius="50dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

focus_tint.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/teal_200"/>
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:color="@color/black"/>

</selector>
```